# How to express a sentence having two for all?

Tags: notation, article-writing

I want to write a sentence in a journal but the sentence has two 'for all's.

For example,

> The variable $x$ is the smallest number such that $f(\zeta x) \le g(a)$ for all $\zeta\in[0,10]$ and for every $a\in A$.

Is it fine if I write like the above?

Another cases are

> The variable $x$ is the smallest number such that $f(\zeta x) \le g(a)$ for all $\zeta\in[0,10]$ and $a\in A$.
>
> The variable $x$ is the smallest number such that, for all $\zeta\in[0,10]$, $f(\zeta x) \le g(a)$ for every $a\in A$.

What is the best expression among them?
If you know better expression, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Why wouldn’t it be fine? All are understandable. I like the second best as it’s the shortest and clearest; the last one confuses me. This question is opinion based (although I suspect most people will tend to like the second version best).

Comment: @k.stm I am worried whether or not the second one implicitly expresses that the constraints are satisfied FOR EVERY $a$ in a set $A$.

Comment: I would definitely read it thay way. Otherwise, I’d expect to see “and *some* $a ∈ A$”. To make that explicit, you could also write “for all $ζ ∈ [0..10]$ and all $a ∈ A$”, which is still very short.

Comment: @k.stm I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to good writing is clarity and simplicity. One way to achieve this is to group things together. Consider the following format:

"... such that *[list of statements]* for every *[list of definitions]*."

As we naturally like to group things, using this format which groups definitions and statements together makes it easy for us to understand what it is conveying.

To answer the above questions, All three expressions are clear and okay to use. Of the three expressions above, the second one is the easiest to understand.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I usually group things together. In this case, however, I do not want to group them since their characteristics are too different. I will use the second one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is not so good as it is more asymmetric and will make people thing that the status of $\zeta$ and $a$ differ. The first is fine.

If you want to stress dependency on two variables, you can also write

> The variable $x$ is the smallest number such that $f(\zeta x) \le g(a)$ for all $\zeta$ and $a$, subject to $\zeta\in[0,10]$ and $a\in A$.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you really mean this? If we are talking only about nonnegative $x$ here then the smallest $x$ satisfying your condition (if there is such an $x$ at all) is $0$.

You could save one "for all" by writing "Let $x_*$ be the smallest (?) $x\geq0$ satisfying
$$f(\zeta x)\leq \inf_{a\in A} g(a)$$
for all $\zeta\in[0,10]$."